# Mocked a method to return true still returns false

Tags: c#, mocking, asp.net-core-webapi, moq, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have a controller method like this :

```cs
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IService fService;
    public ValuesController( IService fService)
    {
        this.fService = fService;            
    }

    public IActionResult InsertDetails( [FromForm]Details details, IFormFile file)
    {
        bool result = fService.SaveDetails(details, file);
        return OK();
    }
}
```

The test case to test this controller is as below:

```cs
public class ValuesControllerTests
{
     readonly Mock<IService> mockService = new Mock<IService>();
     
     [TestMethod]
     public void SaveDetails_Test_Success()
     {
         var details = GetMockDetails(); // gets the sample DTO values
         mockService.Setup(x => x.SaveDetails(details, GetFile())).Returns(true); ---- this is returning false even after mocking the value
         var controller = new ValuesController(mockService.Object);
         controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
         var res = controller.InsertDetails(details, GetFile()) as OkObjectResult;
         Assert.AreEqual("File Details Saved Successfully", res.Value.ToString());
         Assert.AreEqual(200, res.StatusCode);
     }

     IFormFile GetFile()
     {
         return new FormFile(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is a dummy file")), 0, 0, "Data", "dummy.txt");
     }
}
```

Even though I mocked the method `SaveDetails` to return `true`, it always returns `false`.
Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expectation was setup with a different `IFormFile` (reference/instance) than the one that was used when invoking the member under test. This causes the mock to return the default value of the invoked member, which is `false` since it is a boolean.

When `GetFile()` is invoked, it returns a new instance every time.

So either use the same instance, like was done with `details`

```
public void SaveDetails_Test_Success() {
    Details details = GetMockDetails();
    IFormFile file = GetFile(); //single instance
    mockService.Setup(x => x.SaveDetails(details, file)).Returns(true); //used here
    ValuesController controller = new ValuesController(mockService.Object);
    controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
    var res = controller.InsertDetails(details, file) as OkObjectResult; //and here
    Assert.AreEqual("File Details Saved Successfully", res.Value.ToString());
    Assert.AreEqual(200, res.StatusCode);
 }
```

Or loosen up the expectation using argument matchers like `It.IsAny<>()`

```
public void SaveDetails_Test_Success() {
    Details details = GetMockDetails();
    mockService.Setup(x => x.SaveDetails(details, It.IsAny<IFormFile>())).Returns(true); //<-- NOTE
    ValuesController controller = new ValuesController(mockService.Object);
    controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
    var res = controller.InsertDetails(details, GetFile()) as OkObjectResult; 
    Assert.AreEqual("File Details Saved Successfully", res.Value.ToString());
    Assert.AreEqual(200, res.StatusCode);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your `Setup` is that it is too specific.
Please bear mind that parameter matching is based on reference check in case of classes.

```cs
mockService
      .Setup(service => service.SaveDetails(It.IsAny<Details>(), It.IsAny<IFormFile>()))
      .Returns(true);
```

If you would like verify the call then you need to
save the result of the `GetFile` and then make the assertion:

```cs
public void SaveDetails_Test_Success()
{
    //Arrange
    var details = GetMockDetails(); 
    var file = GetFile(); //same instance is used everywhere

    mockService
      .Setup(x => x.SaveDetails(It.IsAny<Details>(), It.IsAny<IFormFile>()))
      .Returns(true); 

    var controller = new ValuesController(mockService.Object);
    controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
    
    //Act
    var result = controller.InsertDetails(details, file);
    
    //Assert
    var res = Assert.IsAssignableForm<OkObjectResult>(result); //Here we test the assignability as well
    Assert.AreEqual("File Details Saved Successfully", res.Value.ToString());
    //Assert.AreEqual(200, res.StatusCode); //This assert is unnecessary

    mockService
      .Verify(x => x.SaveDetails(details, file), Times.Once); 
}
```

Instead of casting the response of the controller's action to `OkObjectResult` I would recommend to assert that as well. (*Just like I did in the above test case*)